# Loop through same classes

Tags: jquery, scrape

I am scraping html of an webpage and the structure goes like this:

```
<p class="h2"></p>
<div class="photoset-col1"></div>
<div class="photoset-col2"></div>
<div class="description"></div>

<p class="h2"></p>
<div class="photoset-col1"></div>
<div class="photoset-col2"></div>
<div class="description"></div>

...continious through out the whole page
```

Now I want to scrape all elements of h2, photoset-col1, photoset-col2, description under each other using jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://theurl',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var result = $(res.responseText).find(".h2").html();




        $( "#container_result" ).append( result );

    }
```

But when I do that it only return the first .h2 class I want them all, do I need a loop for that? And how about the rest photocols and description?

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://theurl',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {
            var result = $(res.responseText).find(".h2, .photoset-col1, .photoset-col2").html();




            $( "#container_result" ).append( result );

        }
```

That doesn't seem to work

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If all the targeted elements are inside a same element, then you can select the parent element and retrieve its html.

Comment: if you invoke `.html()` over a group of elements, then the innerHTML of the first element in that group will be returned. You have to traverse the elements to retrieve all the elements html.

Comment: Yes, they are all inside a div with a class names .content-wrap, but when I select that, it doesn't get any data, I found that strange because all of the content are inside that div...

Comment: Your '#container_result' and '.content-wrap' aren't in your question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append html contents of all .h2

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://theurl',
type: 'GET',
success: function(res) {
    var tempParent = $('<div></div>');
    tempParent.append($(res.responseText).html());
    tempParent.find(".h2").each(function(){
       $( "#container_result" ).append($(this).html());
    });
}
});
```

Comment: what does the div tags do? the h2 is an p tag, does that matter? :-)

Comment: @user253959 You should read up on selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Looking at your html portion that ajax will load it doesn't have a wrapper element. $.find() will search the children of the given context. To create the parent context i created the tempParent as a div and append your html content to that and then applied the find() to search the dom.